# Help printing Serial Monitor to LCD16x2

Tags: serial, lcd

I have a motion sensor that triggers an LED and buzzer. That part works fine and it displays Motion detected in the serial monitor. I'm trying to get the LCD to print that as well but I can't get it to work. The LCD backlight turns on but that's it. At first I tried with the LCD16x2 I2C and now I'm trying with the regular LCD16x2. Here's my code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

const int MOTION_SENSOR_PIN = 7;   // Arduino pin connected to the OUTPUT pin of motion sensor
const int BUZZER_PIN        = 3;   // Arduino pin connected to Buzzer's pincon
int motionStateCurrent      = LOW; // current  state of motion sensor's pin
int motionStatePrevious     = LOW; // previous state of motion sensor's pin
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 6, 5, 4, 2);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);                // initialize serial
  pinMode(MOTION_SENSOR_PIN, INPUT); // set arduino pin to input mode
  pinMode(BUZZER_PIN, OUTPUT);          // set arduino pin to output mode
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
}

void loop() {
  motionStatePrevious = motionStateCurrent;            // store old state
  motionStateCurrent  = digitalRead(MOTION_SENSOR_PIN); // read new state

  if (motionStatePrevious == LOW && motionStateCurrent == HIGH) { // pin state change: LOW -> HIGH
    Serial.println("Motion detected!");
    if (Serial.available()) {
      delay(0);
      lcd.clear();
      while (Serial.available() >0) {
         lcd.print("Motion detected!");
      }
    }
    digitalWrite(BUZZER_PIN, HIGH); // turn on
  }
  else
  if (motionStatePrevious == HIGH && motionStateCurrent == LOW) { // pin state change: HIGH -> LOW
    Serial.println("Motion stopped!");
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      delay(0);
      lcd.clear();
      while (Serial.available()) {
         lcd.print("Motion stopped!");
      }
    }
    digitalWrite(BUZZER_PIN, LOW);  // turn off
  }
}
```

Comment: start with the LCD example sketch instead of your sketch ... at this point, you do not know if the LCD module works correctly

Comment: Why are you using `delay(0)`? You don't need it. Also try to reset the cursor to a known position, before you print to the LCD

Comment: `while (Serial.available())` is != 0 if there's something the SerialMonitor has sent. Until you do a Serial.read() inside the `while`. That means, it would fill your lcd with lots of "Motion stopped!" and seem blocked, then. (probably not your intention)

Comment: Yes the LCD works. Both have been used previously. @DataFiddler what do you mean with !=0? It doesn't need to have the while (Serial.available()). It was just something else I tried because I thought it might be an easier approach. Also, I didn't realize I took out setCursor(0, 0). Ill take out delay and add it again and see if it works.

Comment: `!=` not equal , here the same as `> 0` (Be happy that it doesn't work, it would not work as intended)

Comment: Are you sending anything the Arduino on Serial?  You appear to only be writing and then checking available.  available is for seeing if something is sending TO the arduino, your sending data FROM the arduino won't change available.  IF you want the LCD to display the same as the Serial then put an lcd.print line right after the Serial.print line.  You seem to have some fundamental misunderstanding of what Serial.available() does.